# QtQuick layout margins

Tags: qt, layout, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

Is there any way to remove start and end margins in QML Layout components?

Here is an example of ColumnLayout with a couple of children. The question is how to remove those top and bottom margins and redistribute all children along full height of parent layout.

[image: Margins]

```
ColumnLayout {
    id: dotColumn
    anchors.horizontalCenter: bg.horizontalCenter
    height: root.height
    Repeater {
        id: repeater
        model: root.model

        Item {
            id: activeDot_container

            property int radius: 15
            width: radius * 2
            height: radius * 2

            Rectangle {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                radius: parent.radius

                width: radius * 2
                height: radius * 2

                color: Palette.colors['deepPurple']['500']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, you have to show us your code at least so we can help you.

Comment: @folibis my bad. Code is attached.

Comment: Your code is incomplete so I can only assume how to solve that.Try to add `Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop` to `activeDot_container` item

Comment: @folibis but this way I can get only even bigger margin at the bottom of column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of experiments with layout positioning I've come with following solution.

Assuming that margins I want to eliminate have size of a half of spacing between layout children, we can set negative margins to the beginning and the end of layout component, stretching it till first and last children align at start/end of layout.

Function I used to calculate margins:

```
function getMargin() {
  var height = root.height;
  var spacing = (height - root.radius * 2 * model.length) / model.length;
  return spacing / 2;
}
```

Where `root` is a parent of Layout component, `root.radius*2` represents size of layout child item and can be replaced with another child dimension and `model.length` stands for children count.

Then we can just set anchors for Layout component and set corresponding margins.

```
ColumnLayout {
    anchors.top: root.top
    anchors.bottom: root.bottom
    anchors.topMargin: -1 * getMargin()
    anchors.bottomMargin: -1 * getMargin()
    Repeater {
        model: root.model
        Item {
            property int radius: root.radius
            width: radius * 2
            height: radius * 2
            /* more code */
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Same solution can be applied to RowLayout by replacing layout top/bottom anchors with left/right.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot align item inside Layout both to top and to bottom. As a workaround you can put item with variable `y` inside container as shown below:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    visibility: Window.Maximized

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        height: parent.height
        spacing:1
        Repeater {
            id: repeater
            model: 10
            Rectangle {
                color: "green"
                property int radius: 15
                width: radius
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Rectangle {
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    y: index * (parent.height - height) / (repeater.count - 1)
                    radius: parent.radius
                    width: radius * 2
                    height: radius * 2
                    color: "blue"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is more elegant than the accepted answer.